# how to use a credential file when mounting a samba share using mount command?

Tags: mount, samba

So I often use this command to mount a Samba  share.

```
mount -t cifs //ip/share /mnt/backups -o username=user,password=pwd,domain=domain
```

I want to use a credentials file (with 600 permission) instead of typing in username/password.

Any ideas how this can be done? I've looked around and the only examples I've found are for using a credentials file if I want to auto-mount a Samba share using /etc/fstab.

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you must use the argument `credentials=`

```
mount -t cifs //ip/share /mnt/backups -o credentials=/path/filename
```

quoting from [man mount.cifs](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs)

> `credentials=filename`
>
> specifies a file that contains a username and/or password and optionally the name of the workgroup. The format of the file is:
>
> ```
> username=value
> password=value
> domain=value
> ```

I suggest to create your file under `/root/.smbcredentials_sharename` with permission `600` as you already said.

Make sure NOT to have spaces around the `=` or you will get `permission denied` errors as the values are not correctly taken into account.

Comment: How do you handle it if the password has spaces? I tried enclosing it in double-quotes like password="my password is here" but it didn't like that.

Comment: if it is possible i would change the password with one without spaces in it.